# Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization Codable

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I am trying to create a Response Base to contain API request but I get error `Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization` when using codable. This used to work with a third party library but I am swapping out old data for new one.

```
class ResponseBase: Codable {
    var status: String?
    var message: String?
    var pagination: Pagination?

    var isSucessful: Bool {
        return status == "success"
    }

    struct ErrorMessage {
        static let passwordInvalid = " Current password is invalid."
        static let loginErrorIncorrectInfo = " Incorrect username/password."
        static let loginErrorAccountNotExist = " Invalid request"
    }
}

class Response<T: Codable>: ResponseBase {
    var data: T?

    public func setGenericValue(_ value: AnyObject!, forUndefinedKey key: String) {
        switch key {
        case "data":
            data = value as? T
        default:
            print("---> setGenericValue '\(value)' forUndefinedKey '\(key)' should be handled.")
        }
    }

    public func getGenericType() -> Codable {
        return T()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `getGenericType` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public func getGenericType() -> T.Type {
    return T.self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means just what it says. Merely conforming to Codable does not guarantee that `init` exists, so saying `T()` is illegal. You must make that guarantee yourself. For example:

```
protocol CodableAndInitializable : Codable {
    init()
}
class ResponseBase: Codable {
    // ....
}
class Response<T: CodableAndInitializable>: ResponseBase {
    var data: T?
    // ....
    public func getGenericType() -> Codable {
        return T()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is the answer you're looking for but here you are returning a new object of type `T`. To get the *type* you should return the *type*?

Comment: @mmr118 I agree, but my goal was merely to get rid of the error given the OP's original code.